# ¿Cómo obtener una propiedad anidada de un objeto C#?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, firebase, xamarin

estoy necesitando almacenar en una variable un string llamado **Id** que lo devuelve una de las propiedades anidadas de un `Java.Lang.Object` llamado **result** al finalizar una Query.

El string se encuentra dentro de `result` > `Documents` > `IEnumerator` > `[0]` > `base` > `Id`.

Adjunto captura para mejor comprensión.
[image: ImagenGetID]

Sería ideal algo como:

> **string DocID = result.Documents[0].Id**

Pero no se puede asi.

Ideas para acceder al ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realiza un casting a `QuerySnapshot`.

```
public void OnSuccess(Object result){ 

      var snapshot = (QuerySnapshot) result;
      // string DocID = snapshot.Documents[0].Id
}
```

Comment: Eres un genio compañero! Muchisimas gracias.